# How to get the clicked ListView cell in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

Is there a way to get the clicked `ListView` cell when a user clicks somewhere inside the `ListView`?

I can get the current `ListViewItem` by `SelectedItems[0]` but I don't know which `SubItem` is clicked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle click on a sub-item of ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916183/handle-click-on-a-sub-item-of-listview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SubItems don't have events on their own type.

You can use the [ListViewItem.GetSubItemAt Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.getsubitemat%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to determine what sub item is under the mouse (if any).

Answer (score 1):

ListView.SelectedIndices may help (.net 1.1>)