# Handle click on a sub-item of ListView

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, user-interface

How can I handle click on a sub-item of ListView (detail mode)? i.e. I need to detect what exactly column was clicked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to determine the column by its position:

```
private void listView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point mousePos = listView.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    ListViewHitTestInfo hitTest = listView.HitTest(mousePos);
    int columnIndex = hitTest.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(hitTest.SubItem);
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work on a click event.. but did work on the double click event (.NET 4.5 :)

Comment: This works on click event too, however you cannot place a break point on `Control.MousePosition` It somehow gets updated with new value when you move your mouse even if visual studio is on top, and you'll be spending hours scratching your head to why I click same point every time and still getting different `mousePos`

Comment: I had to enable FullRowSelect on the listview for it to receive Click or MouseClick events when a subitem was clicked.

Answer (score 13):

This is working well for me:

```
    private void listView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var info = listView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
        var row = info.Item.Index;
        var col = info.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(info.SubItem);
        var value = info.Item.SubItems[col].Text;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("R{0}:C{1} val '{2}'", row, col, value));
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `ListView.MouseClick` event as follows:

```
private void listView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Hittestinfo of the clicked ListView location
    ListViewHitTestInfo listViewHitTestInfo = listView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    // Index of the clicked ListView column
    int columnIndex = listViewHitTestInfo.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(listViewHitTestInfo.SubItem);

    ...
}
```

Comment: This also works for MouseUp, MouseDown etc and is cleaner than the accepted answer. +1

Comment: Note: in VS2019 ListView property page the MouseClick event is in "Action" group instead of the "Mouse" group