# How do I make only a certain column in each row clickable?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to make user be able to click a column named `Error Message` and see the `MessageBox` that displays the error message in detail. Right now, I can only click the first column. I want the user be able to click only 4th column (the error message column). How do I achieve this? In summary, I need to make the 4th column in a given row clickable, not any other column.

```
private void LVImportLog_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (LVImportLog.SelectedItems.Count == 0) return;

    LVImportLog.FullRowSelect = true;
    ListViewItem item = LVImportLog.SelectedItems[0];
    string errorMsg = item.SubItems[3].Text.ToString();
    if(errorMsg.Length > 0) MessageBox.Show(errorMsg, errorMsgTitle);
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Handle click on a sub-item of ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17916183/7444103).

Comment: @Jimi Hey thanks! The problem resolved!