# LViewItem of Windows.Forms select with mouseclick

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

In a ListView there are 3 columns. First is the ListViewItem, which has 2 ListViewSubitems. The lines of the program which refers to it are below.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Friend Shared WithEvents LView As ListView = New ListView

    Shared Sub ShowTable(codes As Byte())
        LView.View = View.Details
        LView.Width = 800
        LView.Height = 300
        LView.FullRowSelect = False
        LView.GridLines = True
        LView.Columns.Add("Id1", 200)     'This is ListViewItem
        LView.Columns.Add("Id2", 230)     'This and the next line are the ListViewSubitems
        LView.Columns.Add("Id3", 345)

'Here is the loading of the items of the table
       
        DisplayForm.Controls.Add(LView)  'DisplayForm is the Form's name
        LView.Show()

    End Sub
```

After appearing the table, want to select an item of it with the mouse click on it. This invokes the MouseClick handler, code below

```vb
    Private Shared Sub LView_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles LView.MouseClick

        If e.Button.Equals(MouseButtons.Right) Then
            DelSelected(e)   'This sub define the clicked line
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("This is left click", "Click message", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

MouseClick event is invoked only, when the ListViewItem is clicked. If SubItems clicked nothing happen, even they are on the ListView.
What would be required, that event sub is invoked on the click of the whole line, but the ListViewSubitems remain disabled for any activities implied their values, the mouse click only invoke the handler function to define which element was clicked. Therefore not good the FullRowSelect property set to True. In that case the whole line is colored, and clicking the subitem (instead itself) returns the parent ListItem, so cannot be defined which subitem was clicked. Maybe by the coordinates of the click can define it with a lot of calculation, but very consumable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916183/handle-click-on-a-sub-item-of-listview

Comment: @hans The click is not invoke the click event anywhere on the line, rather the ListViewItem only. The click is ignored.

Comment: [How to get the selected SubItem index in a Listview and highlight it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65860374/7444103)

Comment: @jimi Yes, with these technics i can solve the issue, but really very consumably.

Comment: I don't know what *very consumably* means, but if you don't like the standard behavior of the ListView and you find alternatives difficult to implement, why not just replace the LV with a DataGridView? -- BTW, there's nothing *heavy* in that code, you're just replacing the default rendering of sub-items with your own

Comment: Means that nearly longer than the main program, just because that if you click on ListView somewhere, the click event is only invoked when FullRowSelect=True, and have to deselect and recolor items unnecesserily. If click event would triggered in =False, and return the real value (ListViewSubItem), not the ListViewItem life would be easier.

Comment: @jimi see above, plus the result of HitTest.Item has Index property, but HitTest.SubItem hasn't, while the Text property is available at both. Get used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is: A `ListView` cannot be clicked anywhere rather only "ListViewItem"-s if the property `FullRowSelect=False`.
Furthermore  `ListViewSubitem` hasn't  `Index`, `Selected`, `Focused` properties.
To resolve this issue i applied this in my class where the `ListView` datas are processed.

First change in the ShowTable sub the line

```
LView.FullRowSelect = False
to
LView.FullRowSelect = True
```

In the declaration section

```
    Shared oldcolor1 As Color = Nothing, oldcolor2 As Color = Nothing
    Shared selitemindex As Integer = 0, selsubitemindex As Integer = 0
    Shared oldcolor1 As Color = Nothing, oldcolor2 As Color = Nothing
    Shared selitemindex As Integer = 0, selsubitemindex As Integer = 0
```

In the Sub procedure

```
        Private Shared Sub ItemSelected(e As MouseEventArgs)

        Dim coordx, coordy, buttpress As Integer
        Dim rowitem As ListViewItem
        Dim info As ListViewHitTestInfo
        If Not oldcolor1.IsEmpty Then
            With LView.Items(selitemindex).SubItems(selsubitemindex)
                .BackColor = oldcolor1
                .ForeColor = oldcolor2
            End With
        End If
        coordx = e.Location.X
        coordy = e.Location.Y
        rowitem = LView.GetItemAt(coordx, coordy)
        info = LView.HitTest(coordx, coordy)
        selitemindex = info.Item.Index
        selsubitemindex = info.Item.SubItems.IndexOf(info.SubItem)
        With LView.Items(selitemindex)
            .Focused = False
            .Selected = False
            oldcolor1 = .BackColor
            oldcolor2 = .ForeColor
            .UseItemStyleForSubItems = False
            .SubItems(selsubitemindex).BackColor = Color.DodgerBlue
            .SubItems(selsubitemindex).ForeColor = Color.White
        End With
    End Sub
```

Only for extending varieties, instead of `HitTest` method, `ListView.FocusedItem` property  can be used, of course code must adjust to it. As you like.
Has to know that ListViewSubItem in this case neither `Focused`  nor `Selected`.
Part of  this code based on the linked sheets in the comments of the question. There additional infos can be found on this subject.
So, this how i got through it.